# What's wrong with this LL grammar? (very short)

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsing

```
S --> Ta | b | Sc
T --> Tc | λ
```

This isn't an LL grammar but I need it to be so I can do a parse table. The problem is that no matter how much I try I never manage to do make it an LL grammar. Can someone please help by making it a LL grammar? It isn't that big and I'm very confused.

Comment: Have you tried using an example and seeing where you go wrong? AT which stage of the tree construction that you find the problem?

Comment: I'm using JFLAP to create the parse table but I can't manage to make it LL, I always get "unrestricted at left side".

Comment: S --> TaS' | bS' /////
S'--> cS'|λ //////
T--> cT | λ /////

but seems like I just can't do it and I bet that's wrong ^

Comment: What is the grammar for? What are you trying to parse? What kind of string or expression?

Comment: If you search the webs and even cs.SE for "remove left recursion", you will find algorithms that do so. Please try to apply them and refocus your question if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

First note that $T = c^*$ (using regular expression syntax). We can therefore rewrite your grammar to:

```
S --> c*a | b | Sc
```

Rewriting even further, we can say that $S = (c^*a | b)c^*$, so $S$ is regular. It is not hard to come up with a grammar for this language:

```
S --> T a T | b T
T --> c T | λ
```

More generally, when trying to rewrite grammars to $LL$ form, one first removes left recursion using standard techniques (for instance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion)). Then one tries to remove any conflicts that are left, for which no general techniques are known - just try to figure out what the conflict means, and try to solve it accordingly.

Comment: You could just have given a right-regular grammar.